# Handling multiple domains in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with a Rails app that handles traffic for multiple domains. I have accomplished this by using constraints in my routes using:

```
constraints domain: 'foo.com' do
...
end

constraints domain: 'bar.com' do
...
end
```

Everything works fine until I try to do a `redirect_to @user` from bar.com. It ends up redirecting through the route foo.com, as that one appear first in my routes.rb file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncertain this is 100% "the way" as I am not sure of any business constraints you may be under, but it would seem that something like this would work (and maybe will help as a good jumping off point):

```
# in your controller method 
def w00t
  # the_current_host in my example is "dynamic" but could be static 
  # should that better fit your needs, of course 
  the_current_host = request.protocol + request.host
  redirect_to user_url(@user, host: the_current_host)
end
```

Note that I just "randomly" picked `request.protocol` and `request.host` ... you could explore the [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object) and decide the right ones for you.

Comment: Thank you. This did indeed work. Any idea as to why the redirect by itself was not catching?

Comment: Excellent! I'm not totally certain but my sense was, given your stated requirements, being explicit about the host would ensure it always worked as expected. Sorry I don't have a better explanation than that at the moment!